# How to return 'negative' of a value in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, is there any function that returns the negative of the values in a column?

Comment: return the `value` and then do a `-value`. Is that you want?

Comment: @sk11 -- <joke>That's an operator, not a function.  OP probably wants `operator.neg` ;-)</joke> -- or as a method call:  `value.__neg__()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the negative sign on the column directly.  For instance, if your DataFrame has a column "A", then `-df["A"]` gives the negatives of those values.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [lambda](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) function and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).
For example if I want negative values from column "value" I write something like this:

```
import pandas as pn
file_name = './exmp.txt'
names = ['class', 'value']
df = pn.read_csv(file_name, sep=': ', names=names, engine='python')
f = lambda x: -x
df['value'].apply(f)
```

#### Update

BrenBarn [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25562736/1571875) is much better, just add `-` before column name so for my example it would be:

```
import pandas as pn
file_name = './exmp.txt'
names = ['class', 'value']
df = pn.read_csv(file_name, sep=': ', names=names, engine='python')
-df['value']
```

It's much easier.

Comment: Well, I think @BrenBarn answer is much better, I will include it in my post as well

Comment: Actually, I mistakenly accepted your answer.. Anyways, thanks a lot for ur response :)